# Splitting Data into Training and Testing Set in the prescence of categorical features of multiple levels

Tags: r, machine-learning, training-data

I wish to perform an ordinary machine learning model, e.g., logistic regression, random forest, etc...

One or more of my features are categorical with many levels. Let's assume that I cannot find an easy way of combining levels.

If I simply split the data into training and test, some levels will be in the test set but not in the training set, and the prediction will fail.

How do I split the data in R, while guaranteeing that each level of each categorical variable will be in both the training set and test set?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `dplyr::slice_sample` function:

eg

```
full_data <- iris
train <- dplyr::slice_sample(full_data, prop = .7, by=Species)
test <- dplyr::anti_join(full_data, train)
```

Note that this code will drop duplicated entries